What is the DNS address of a Pod in a StatefulSet?
I normally use a service to access the pod (statefulset-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local). However, I'm trying to access directly the pod. How can I do that without the need of the IP address of the pod?
Something like this basically
pod-0.my-namespace.pod.cluster.local
Reference: A/AAAA records for Pods (in here, it mentions the IP address but that doesn't work for me since the IP might change by time)

Normally you should access Pods by accessing it's Service.
For StatefulSet it might be useful to access the pods directly since they have stable network identity. To do this via DNS, you must first create a Headless Service, a Service with clusterIP: None. Like:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-stateful-app
  labels:
    app: my-stateful-app
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 1234
      name: app
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: my-stateful-app

then, you can get the IP's of all pods in your StatefulSet on DNS name:
$(service name).$(namespace).svc.cluster.local

and the individual Pod names with (Pod name is your StatefulSet name + an ordinal, e.g. my-statefulset-app-2):
$(podname).$(service name).$(namespace).svc.cluster.local

